# I used puppeteer in vscode to convert a md file to pdf, however, all formulas in my file were gone after converting

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown, puppeteer

This picture is a preview of an MD file which include formulas using MPE in VSCode:
[before converting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTAQ2.png)
Then I convert this file to pdf using **puppeteer**, **all formulas are gone!**
[after converting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7uUi.png)
I don't know what happened. Hope somebody can help me. Thank you!

Comment: What's the code that was used for converting? The second screenshot seems to have Unicode characters but there's no obvious way (to me) to tell if they're from utf-8 or utf-16. If you're using the default it's likely utf-8 as that's a standard for the web nowadays, so try giving it a shot with the opposite. If you're unsure what the default is it should be in the documentation, but you can always just try both 8 and 16 explicitly.

Comment: I use the following method to convert MD file, and the MD file is encoded by utf-8. The picture is below.